# Not understand Scanset combination in scanf

Tags: c

I cannot understand how this scanset work

```
scanf("%*[^:]%*2c%[^\n]", str1);// 1st scanf
```

full code is

```
int main()
{
    int ch;
    char str1[100];
    printf("Enter input\n");
    scanf("%*[^:]%*2c%[^\n]", str1);
    printf("input is: %s",str1);
return 0;
}
```

If input is  `

> Any combination: You are free to use any combination.

Output is

> input is:  You are free to use any combination.

when I remove `%*[^:]` from scanf

now scanf is `scanf("%*2c%[^\n]", str1);  //2nd scanf`

With same Input

> Any combination: You are free to use any combination.

Output is

> input is: y combination: You are free to use any combination.

So if I remove `%*2c` from first scanf

now scanf is `scanf("%*[^:]%[^\n]", str1);   \\3rd scanf`

Input is

> Any combination: You are free to use any combination.

Output is

> input is: : You are free to use any combination.

Agian if I remove `%[^\n]` from first scanf.

now scanf is `scanf("%*[^:]%*2c", str1);   \\4th scanf`

Input is

> Any combination: You are free to use any combination.

Output is

> garbage value.

Question is how  scanset in each scanf work? Please explain step by step.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%*[^:]%*2c%[^\n]", str1);`  The buffer length for `str1[]` is 100 characters and the input format specifier '%[...]` always appends a NUL byte to the input, so that specifier should have a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  I.E.  `scanf("%*[^:]%*2c%99[^\n]", str1);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the `scanf` documentation on at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf:

> conversion specifications. Each conversion specification has the following format:
>
> - introductory % character
> - (optional) assignment-suppressing character *. If this option is present, the function does not assign the result of the conversion to any receiving argument.
> - (optional) integer number (greater than zero) that specifies maximum field width, that is, the maximum number of characters that the function is allowed to consume when doing the conversion specified by the current conversion specification.
>
> ...
>
> **[set]**
>
> - matches a non-empty sequence of character from set of characters.
>     If the first character of the set is ^, then all characters not in the set are matched...

So breaking down your format string:

`%*[^:]` - Match everything up to a `:`, but don't assign to a variable. Essentially ignores everything before a colon.

`%*2c` - Match 2 characters but again don't assign them. So skips the colon and the character after.

`%[^\n]` - Match everything up to `\n` (new line character), this gets assigned to `str1`. So everything after the first colon and the following character gets matched and assigned here.

So with the input `Any combination: You are free to use any combination.`, the ignored part is `Any combination:`  and the result in `str1` is `You are free to use any combination.`

#### Further notes

The reason the `scanf("%*[^:]%*2c", str1)` results in garbage being printed is because neither of the format specifiers assign `str1` leaving it uninitialised. The byte values that happen to be in the memory for the `str1` array are what get printed, hence the nonsense. This case, where there are unused arguments to `scanf` (or `printf`) style functions should be warned about by most modern compilers. So please make sure that you have your warnings turned on, and that you try to interpret and fix them.

The same thing can happen with your full format string if the input doesn't contain a `:`, in which case `scanf` will never reach the part that assigns `str1` and your result will be garbage again. To get around this you need to look at the return value of `scanf`:

> #### Return value
>
> Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.

In this case you would get `EOF` since the input would end before `str1` is assigned. To make sure `str1` is valid, you need to check that the return value is `1`.

Finally, as mentioned in the comments, there is another issue here that if the user types input after the skipped part that is larger than the `str1` array can hold. Note that `scanf` will automatically add a terminating `\0` to then end of the string, so the maximum length for the assigned section of input it is 99 characters. If the input is larger, it will go off the end of the buffer and overwrite memory it is not supposed to. This will most likely cause the program to behave strangely or crash. The format string can be made safe by adding a maximum field width specifier to the conversion specifier. In short, change `%[^\n]` to `%99[^\n]`.